# delete i-th element from every field of structure

Tags: matlab

I have a structure named `phonebook` with various field: `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`. A typical example:

```
phonebook.first_name(1) = 'Roger'
phonebook.last_name(1)= 'Maxwell'
phonebook.phone_number(1) = '+3123-231232'
```

Sometimes I need to completely delete a record, so I write something like:

```
phonebook.first_name(i) = []
phonebook.last_name(i)= []
phonebook.phone_number(i) = []
```

Is there is a way to delete the i-th record without the need to write each field? A sort of:

```
phonebook.*(i) = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a structure array instead of a structure *of* arrays?

```
phonebook(1) = struct('field1', 1, 'field2', 'A');
phonebook(2) = struct('field1', 2, 'field2', 'B');
```

Then it is easy to delete an entire record:

```
phonebook(1) = []

phonebook = 

    field1: 2
    field2: 'B'
```

Here is a good post talking about the difference: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/04/22/matlab-basics-array-of-structures-vs-structures-of-arrays/

Comment: I have to frequently sort the field. In this way sorting is more complicated.

Comment: Not at all...just use this great FileExchange pick: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28573-nested-sort-of-structure-arrays. Or, if you're only sorting 1 field, you can do it manually just like: `[~, idx] = sort([phonebook.field1]); phonebook = phonebook(idx);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that?

```
a.b=[1 2 3];
a.c=[2 3 4];
for f=fieldnames(a)', a.(f{1})(1)=[]; end
a

a = 

    b: [2 3]
    c: [3 4]
```